# Java generic method: inconsistency when inferring upper bound on return type from argument type

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, type-erasure

Consider the following:

```
class Col<T> { }
class Tag<T> { }
class Foo { }
class Bar { }
class Baz extends Bar { }
class Test {
   static <T, V extends T> Col<V> safe (Tag<T> t) { return null; }
   static <T, V extends T> Col<V> unsafe (T t) { return null; }
}
```

then this will generate a desired compile-time error (since Baz doesn't extend Foo):

```
Col<Baz> col = Test.safe (new Tag<Foo> ());
```

but this will not:

```
Col<Baz> col = Test.unsafe (new Foo ());
```

and for reference, this compiles as intended (since Baz extends Bar):

```
Col<Baz> col = Test.safe (new Tag<Bar> ());
```

Why is it that the compiler (Java 8) can infer and use T as an upper bound on the return type parameter in the 'safe' case, but not in the 'unsafe' case?

I think I understand why it doesn't work in the 'unsafe' case due to T being erased by Object, but maybe a bit surprised it works in the 'safe' case. At least I find it to be inconsistent.

Comment: It seems odd that it infers T as Object, because this is almost exactly why you would be using generics. If you're explicit it won't work: `Col<Baz> col = Test.<Foo, Baz>unsafe(new Foo ());`

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that a Foo is an Object, but a Tag<Foo> is not a Tag<Object>. See this related question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/6253321

Comment: @cppbeginner I don't agree. The problem isn't that Tag<Foo> doesn't work. That is the way it is supposed to be, how does your linked question show that Test.unsafe shouldn't throw a compiler error.

Comment: @matt It doesn’t - the linked question explains why the first safe() example does give a compiler error (the inferred type of Object for the unsafe() example doesn’t work for the safe() example due to the lack of covariance). If you replace Col<V> and Tag<T> by array types V[] and T[], the safe() example compiles - this is because arrays are covariant.

Comment: Why isn't T used as the upper bound in the unsafe case?

Comment: I agree with the provided answer now, Just kinda goes to show you should set your bounds.

Comment: @cppbeginner Ok, Tag<Foo> not being Tag<Object> makes sense, but why does Tag<Bar> work then (while equally not being Tag<Object>)?

Comment: In that example the compiler infers Bar for T and Baz for V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Col<Baz> col = Test.unsafe (new Foo ());
```

`Test.unsafe` infers `T` as `Object` in this case; since everything extends `Object`, the bounds are satisfied.

```
Col<Baz> col = Test.safe (new Tag<Foo> ());
```

`T` can't be inferred to be `Object` in this case: it's `Foo`, because you've said that it's `Foo`, without any bounds. Similarly, `V` is exactly `Baz`. Since `Baz` doesn't extend `Foo`, it's a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, this answer together with the clarification from @cpp beginner about Tag<Foo> not being assignable to Tag<Object> makes it clear. To summarise: in the 'usafe' case it is possible to replace T with a type that makes the code compile with Baz on the left hand side and Foo on the right. In the corresponding 'safe' case there is no such type to replace T with.